# Change RStudio library path at home directory

Tags: path, r, rstudio

Each time RStudio starts, it checks and creates ~/R if it doesn't exist. I want to change this path elsewhere. How can I do this configuration?

I know that

```
HOME=/some/path rstudio
```

will work. But can I configure through some config file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got answer:

Edit file `~/.Renviron`, add

```
R_LIBS_USER=/some/path
```

Next time RStudio starts, it will create directories in `/some/path` instead of `~/R`.

Answer (score 1):

I found really useful this post:

https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-set-a-variable-in-renviron/5029/4

It shows hwo you can also use an helper function you can find in the package `usethis` to modify `.Renviron`:

```
usethis::edit_r_environ()
```